# Excel Range choose to auto fill (by given to rows' paramaters

Tags: excel

Saying I have column A B C,
column A&B's rows < columnC's row (e.g. A&B has 500 rows while C has 1000 rows)

I set A and B's last rows = previous_lastrow
C's last rows=lastrow

how can I write my script to autofill from A:B.previous_lastrow to last row (as same as column C)?

I only know how to write script like this : 
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("K2:K" & lastrow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try as follows.

Note: I am assuming A and B are not jagged. You may wish to calculate `lastRowB` as well, and if `lastRowB < lastRowA` then substitute `lastRowB` in for `lastRowA` in   `.Range("A" & lastRowA & ":B" & lastRowA).AutoFill`

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub FillDownInfo()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim lastRowA As Long, lastRowC As Long, lastRowD As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        lastRowA = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        lastRowC = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
        lastRowD = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("A" & lastRowA & ":B" & lastRowA).AutoFill Destination:=.Range("A" & lastRowA & ":B" & lastRowC), Type:=xlFillDefault '<== change to A1 if no headers
        .Range("D" & lastRowD).AutoFill Destination:=.Range("D" & lastRowD & ":D" & lastRowC), Type:=xlFillDefault
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, Range("A" & lastRowA & ":B" & lastRowA) is something I am looking for :)   (I just don't know how to write the correct scipt in this way...)

Comment: The same! haha thanks but I suddenly have another question: for example, I auto fill A and B down but at the same time, I also want to auto fill column D down as well (A,B,D has the same number of row and < the row of column C)   how can I write the script to put, A, B D down together?

Comment: Thanks！ (at first I thought I can put the three columns together :)  in one sentence   but seems to be not very possible

Comment: Nope. If you think about it, you can't do that manually either.